# Полоса прокрутки на форме в Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

Как добавить полосу прокрутки на форму в Qt? 
Добавил verticalScrollBar на форму. Как его активировать? Подскажите пожалуйста)

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вам нужен не QScrollBar, а [QScrollArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#details)

```
QScrollArea scrollArea = new QScrollArea();
scrollArea->setWidget(yourWidget);
```